# Tfint (Interleved 2 of 5) not recognized on Panasonic FZ-F1 using UWP Sample

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/20f72fc1650e0c46693dea7ab57ed8705a2997fe/Samples/BarcodeScanner), along with a Panasonic FZ-F1, which is currently restricted to build 1511 (10586) because a newer version of [Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise in not available yet.](http://pc-dl.panasonic.co.jp/toughpad/windows/handheld_tablet.html#topicsF104)

The issue I've encountered is that it seems to be unable to identify TfInt (I2of5). It successfully scans other barcodes with no issue. The included app (which appears to be in Silverlight), Barcode Reader has a demo mode, which seems to work fine with I2of5. However, in order for it to work correctly, I had to set the barcode length (10 in this case). I don't see a way to set this using the UWP sample.

I set TfInt as an ActiveSymbology...

```
await claimedScanner.SetActiveSymbologiesAsync(
    new List<uint> { BarcodeSymbologies.TfInt }
);
```

But without being able to assign the length, it doesn't seem to recognize I2of5.

Suggestions as a work around are welcome.

Comment: While I don't know about the Panasonic unit in particular, many I2of5 readers require explicitly setting the length for I2of5 codes because a scan which goes diagonally through an I2of5 code without hitting both ends would have a significant likelihood of appearing as a valid (but wrong) code.  Configuring I2of5 readers for a particular expected length can help avoid that problem.

Comment: @supercat Understood. Any idea how to configure the length using Windows.Devices.PointOfService with UWP v1511? There appears to be an overload for SetActiveSymbologies with an argument for [BarcodeSymbologyAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodesymbologyattributes) in v1703, which support DecodeLength1/2.

Comment: It seems commonplace for I2of5 readers to allow configuration of two acceptable lengths.  So try setting `DecodeLength1` to a desired length (if you want two different lengths of symbols, set `DecodeLength2` to the other).

Comment: @supercat I can't set it, because I'm using an older version of the UWP API v1511(10586), because my device doesn't support 1703.  I was hoping for a way around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panasonic ended up swapping out the hardware. The reason the barcode didn't work is that it requires that the symbology to be configured in an app on the device that is pre-installed. This app wasn't present on any of our devices because somehow we received test units.

Answer (score 0):

Win10 Ver1703 for FZ-F1 has been available.
http://pc-dl.panasonic.co.jp/toughpad/windows/handheld_tablet.html#F1_sched
http://cpt.pc-dlp.panasonic.co.jp/toughpad/download/osv/FZ-F1_Upgrade1511to1703_r1.0.pdf

Comment: @Yan I understand that the link shows that the update is available, but reality doesn't mesh with their website. I've tried on multiple occasions to download the update, and it doesn't work. I've also been in touch with their technical support and have an open support ticket with their tier 2 support about the issue. I have multiple FZ-F1 devices, and the update won't download for any of them. Have you successfully updated one with model number FZ-F1BBCAZZM?